# Pass data to a @section in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know you can't use @RenderSection to pass data but what would be the equivalent to achieve the below?  I'm trying to send back to a partial view that value of item.Enabled

This is the layout page for a drop down DropDown.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items){
    <li>
        @RenderSection("Item", false)//How to pass 'item.IsChecked' back ?
        <span class="key">@item.Key</span>
        <span class="value">@item.Value</span>                  
    </li>
}
```

This partial view that calls the above. I want to use this when specifically creating drop downs with check boxes.

```
@model DropDownCheckBox
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/DropDown.cshtml";
}
@section Item{
    <input type="checkbox" @(Model.IsChecked ? "checked=yes" : string.Empty) />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@RenderSection()` is the same concept of `@RenderBody()`

What you should use in your case is `@Html.Partial("ViewName", YourModel)` or `@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", YourModel)`  instead.

Comment: I see, but how do I pass back only a part of the view model?  In my case I want to pass back to the @section Item the IsChecked property...